# Бот не реагирует на /start

Tags: python, telebot

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot('token')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def main(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите расписание вашей группы')

bot.polling(none_stop = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Код рабочий, если токен не забыли вставить)

Если запускаете локально, то скорее всего проблемы в передачи данных от вашего устройства, возможно антивирус мешает.

Для теста можете залить код на pythonanywhere.com, бесплатный хостинг, боты на telebot спокойно работают, и загрузка не требует особых знаний работы с различными ОС, всё интуитивно понятно

Answer (score -1):

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot('ваш токен')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def handle_start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите расписание вашей группы')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```